# How can I align this Wordpress image caption with the top of the image?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, image

I'm writing a Wordpress theme. I'd like the captions I add to my images in the theme to be pulled to the left of an image and aligned with the top of the image, like the picture below:

[image]

The HTML output by Wordpress looks like this (simplified for clarity):

```
<div id="attachment_1726" style="width: 1034px" class="wp-caption aligncenter">
   <a href="some_url"><img class="wp-image-1726 size-large" src="the_src" width="1024" height="640"></a>
   <p class="wp-caption-text">Satoshi town, the trading capital of BitQuest</p>
</div>
```

I can't figure out how to pull the `wp-caption-text` paragraph out. I;ve tried the following:

```
.wp-caption-text {
  position: relative;
  left: -170px;
  top: 0;
  width: 150px;
}
```

But this doesn't work. Here's the result:

[image]

Can anyone point me in the correct direction?

Answer (score 0):

You have to float both elements. Also may apply `vertical-align: top;`

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 450px;
}
p,
img {
  float: left;
}
p {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

  <p>Satoshi town, the trading capital of BitQuest</p>
  <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=350%C3%97150&w=350&h=150" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to display it as inline-block:

```
.wp-caption-text {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  left: -170px;
  top: 0;
  width: 150px;
}
```